# Latitude and longitude of the destination of an airplane, given its speed and direction of travel

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

#### Problem

A plane leaves an airport X, $20.6$ degree east and $36.8$ degree north, and flies due south along the same longitude for 8hrs at the rate of 1000km/h to another airport Y, $20.6$ degree east and $\theta$ degree south. The plane then flies west to another airport Z for 8hrs at the same speed. Calculate:

(a) the value of $\theta$
(b) the longitude of $Z$

#### Progress

For the (a) part I used the speed and time to get the distance. Then I used the formula to find distance along great circles to find the unknown in part a. I got the answer to be $34.8$. I do not know how to do the b part.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! People here are willing to help you but don't you think it could be good you show your efforts ? Explain what you tried and tell where you are stuck.

Comment: I tried the a part and I got the answer to be 34.8 I do not know how to do the b part

Comment: Describe your work; be sure it will be better percieved.

Comment: I used the speed and time to get the distance. Then I used the formula to find distance along great circles to find the unknown in part a